# Why can't I obtain a text view by ID even though it seems to be properly declared?

Tags: android, android-layout

I created this app using Android Studio, starting from a paged activity template. I have done little modifications, such as adding 2 text views within the layout. So from my understanding, the manifest should already have been prepared correctly. I also pasted the manifest.

My application has 2 `_main.xml`s. This is fragment_main.xml where the 2 textviews are declared (they are showing up where they should on the screen).

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_audio_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.axonnsd.musicnexus.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Now playing:"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/now_playing_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Now playing.."
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.axonnsd.musicnexus.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And I'm trying to set the text in `now_playing_text` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES.

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.now_playing_text)).setText("test");

}
```

As soon as I start my app, it crashes with the following error:

```
05-12 09:51:16.108 7671-7671/org.axonnsd.musicnexus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.axonnsd.musicnexus, PID: 7671
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.axonnsd.musicnexus/org.axonnsd.musicnexus.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.axonnsd.musicnexus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:170)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.axonnsd.musicnexus">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you declared the Activity in the Manifest file ?

Comment: I don't see the FAB in the layout, and yet it crashes on the TextView. Are you sure you are using the correct layout?

Comment: Is the layout you pasted activity_main.xml?

Comment: The xml posted is the activity_main.xml? It looks like is anotherone, in the posted xml you dont have the container element that you are calling in onCreate method.

Comment: you are missing the FAB in the layout file due to which the ifindViewById is returning a null. Make sure you are using the correct layout.

Comment: I pasted in the manifest. I created this app starting from a template, with very few modifications (just adding 2 text views). Also, for those that voted -1, I think it's rather poor form to do this without explanation, or to vote -1 before I even get a chance to answer. It seems to have become common practice on SO to downvote "just so". Am I missing something?

Comment: @JonathanAste true, I pasted fragment_main, which is where I added the two text views (which correctly show on the screen where they should). I will update my answer to include activity_main.xml as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findViewById is returning a null value.

the id does not exist in the layout which appears to be because you are trying to reference it from your activity when it seems to be in the fragment layout.

Findviewbyid when called from an Activity will only find widgets in the activity and not from any child fragment layouts it may contain.

To access a view inside a fragment, call FindViewById from the fragment that contains it.

If you need to then access the TextView from the Activity, you can do so by setting up an interface to communicate between the two components as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Comment: I know why it's crashing :). I know it returns null. I pasted the layout. It's there.

Comment: by "dumbing down" your code\layout, you are making it impossible to give a definitive answer as your code references several id's which are not in the layout. container, fab, toolbar etc How would we know which ones are really there?

Comment: I wasn't aware that I forgot to paste an XML file. I updated my answer. I'd appreciate people give a chance for reply before voting -1. I don't find that too fair and is discouraging to people using this website.  Not sure if I got a -1 from you or not, but I'm a bit upset that people jump on the -1 without being transparent about it.

Comment: Updated answer based on your additional information In the question.

Comment: Any quick tips on how I should actually be getting that text view? :)

Comment: you must call `findViewById` in the fragment you are using that uses the view it is contained in

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is not `R.layout.activity_main`
As I see this is `PlaceholderFragment`,
I think the fragment was not injected into `activity_main`

Comment: I was missing activity_main from my question. I added it now.